# Composite knots and their braid words

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, braid-groups

Given a composite knot K = K_1 # K_2, I wonder how the braid word looks like. Is it possible to see from the word that the knot is composite?

I am not aware of a statement such as "the closure of a braid of a given form is a composite knot" and wouldn't hope for it. But then there is Vogel's algorithm, perhaps something similar more advanced can give an organised way to keep the sum visible somehow when bringing the knot K into a braid presentation?

Comment: You can give at least *a* braid representative for $K_1 \# K_2$: if $\beta_1$ is a braid in the generators $\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_{n_1-1}$ for $K_1$ and $\beta_2$ is a braid word in the generators $\sigma_{n_1+1},\dots,\sigma_{n_1+n_2-1}$ for $K_2$, then $\beta_1\sigma_{n_1}\beta_2$ is a braid whose closure is $K_1\#K_2$. For instance, $\sigma_1^3\sigma_2\sigma_3^2$ is a connected sum of two trefoils. (It's likely you can get rid of the "middle" generator $\sigma_{n_1}$, but it helps to visualise the sphere that exhibits the connected sum.)

Comment: In standard English one says "what it looks like" or "how it looks", but not "how it looks like". In this case, "what it looks like" is more to the point, since "how it looks" has a connotation of "how good it looks."

Answer (score 5):

Birman and Menasco show that the `composite braid representation' described by Marco Golla in his comment is in some sense canonical. That is, you can get from an arbitrary braid word to the one that Marco describes by a series of moves. See Birman-Menasco, Studying links via closed braids. IV. Composite links and split links, Invent. Math. 102 (1990), no. 1, 115–139.

There is also a later erratum in Invent. Math. 160 (2005), no. 2, 447–452 that corrects the proof; the statement remains the same. The erratum refers to a lot of subsequent work that might be useful.

Comment: Great, that is the direction I am looking for. If anyone knows an implementation that checks for the existence of moves to such a 'composite braid representation' whenever it exists (and others tells me that it does not), please let me know!